# Pagination error when using with element

Tags: cakephp, element, paginator

I habve a view from table which is working fine with pagination (Paginator->sort()) when I am using it as a view. But when i changed is as a element, it will throw errors:

```
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\paginator.php, line 194]<br>
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\paginator.php, line 194]<br>
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\paginator.php, line 378]<br>
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\paginator.php, line 378]<br>
```

The code is exacty same as before, but I changed of course some of the code as follows:

Model:Added next statement

```
var $helpers = array('Paginator');
```

Controller: changed the paginate clause to return values to element

```
return $collaborations = $this->paginate('Collaboration');
```

Element: added request action into start of the element and the other line is how I call the parination sort

```
<?php $collaborations = $this->requestAction('/collaborations/calendar'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Pvm','Collaboration.start_date'); ?>
```

Why can't my pagination sort functionality work? Do I have declare something else? I did some Googling and I figured out that paginator might have problem to see/find datamodel (to be declared somewhere) or it would need some parameters to be assigned into it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Check cakephp book: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1231/Pagination

You have to set up  the paginate variable in your controller and then use the method paginate to populate the data in the view.

Helpers should be configured in the controller not in the model.

Example, your controller class should look like:

```
class ColaborationController extends AppController {
    var $paginate = array( 'limit'=>25, 'order'=>array('Colaboration.start_date'=>'asc'));

    function some_action() {
        $this->set('collaborations', $this->paginate('Collaboration'));
    }
}
```

And your view:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Pvm','collaboration.start_date'); ?>
```

Comment: Actually, this example above worked fine when using with view. The way you described, will give both "invalid arguments" (dataset is not working) and array_merge error. You have to remember, that this view is ran as a element, and data has to be returned to element like this: **return** $collaborations = $this->paginate('Collaboration');

Comment: When changing controller line to: return $collaborations = $this->paginate('Collaboration'); fetching dataset is working. But still problems with paginate sorting. I changed everything else, but no luck.

Comment: I'm using cakephp 1.3 and it works like I wrote (i also have elements with pagination), i dont know, maybe in next version it doesnt work.

Comment: Try this when you call your element: $this->element('col_element', $colaborations)

Comment: Some comments and observations. I am using CakePHP 1.3. The Containable Behavior has not been enbled or configured.

Comment: Same errors in here (more details), but this thread ended without any result: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Paginator-gt-sort-on-associated-model-field-td3257442.html

Comment: Can you check with pr($colaborations) or something if the element has the variable to paginate?

Answer (score 0):

I got bored trying to resolve this problem. I changed the whole application logic around and now it works fine. No problems with paginations in elements (no pagination elements at all) and I don't have to use requestAction method - I read that it is not good for performance and should be avoided. Thanks all for your help :)